# How to exclude unused parts of lodash from Marionette 3 app using Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, marionette, lodash

I have a dummy app with next dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "backbone": "^1.3.3",
  "backbone.marionette": "^3.1.0",
  "jquery": "^3.1.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
  "webpack": "^2.2"
}
```

And a webpack.config.js with something like

```
{
  entry: {
    app: './empty-file.js',
    vendor: ['backbone.marionette']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
      underscore: 'lodash'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor')
  ],
```

When I'm running webpack, I'm getting whole lodash lib in the bundle. It is huge, bigger than everything else combined. As I understand, it is Marionette who makes something like `import _ from 'lodash'`. Is there a way to remove not needed parts of lodash?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`babel-plugin-lodash`](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash) to remove the unneeded parts.

**Before**

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import { add } from 'lodash/fp';

const addOne = add(1);
_.map([1, 2, 3], addOne);
```

**After**

```js
import _add from 'lodash/fp/add';
import _map from 'lodash/map';

const addOne = _add(1);
_map([1, 2, 3], addOne);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, looks like a good option for most cases. Unfortunately one of the requirements of the plugin is "You must use ES2015 imports to load Lodash" but as I understand Marionette uses commonjs `require` to import underscore/lodash http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette.html

Comment: The source code uses ES2015 imports: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/backbone.marionette.js The code in the doc is probably not up-to-date.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! They are providing compiled file as "main" and excluding the src folder from package with `.npmignore` file. Even if I'm stating github url as dependency npm downloads it without src.